# Project file changed many places

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project, xcodeproj

My project contains many files and third-party frameworks and so on.
Working as a team, When I'm adding a single file to the project it's showing many changes in the project file, How can we set project file to show only my changes. It should not change the project file in many places and remote changes. Actually, I have seen some **rake tidy** command to show only our changes. Is there any way like that?

Comment: consider adding a screenshot.

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore?  What's in it?